Inspector window error for setting value in Shader graph in Unity URP TextMeshPro
We are currently using TextMeshPro 3.2.0-pre.10 on 2D Unity 2022.3.43f1 and URP 14.0.11.
I want to put the Dissolve effect in the URP shader graph of that TextMeshPro, so I worked on it and created a float value there (Exposed checked), but the float value does not appear in the inspector window of the material for that setup. Does anyone know how to fix this?
enter image description here
enter image description here

Are you sure you saved and recompiled the shader? Is it a shader that does have a custom editor implementation overruling the default drawers?
